# How many strings of length |w| are unrelated?

Tags: strings, data-compression, kolmogorov-complexity

For sufficiently large |w|, how many of the 2^|w| strings of length |w| are entirely unrelated?

A way to define this: two strings are unrelated if their joint Kolomogorov complexity is practically equal to their individual Kolmogorov complexities added together: K(w1,w2)=K(w1)+K(w2)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask "How many items are Y" if Y is a binary relationship between two items; that only makes sense if Y is a property of a single item.  Are you looking for the maximum-sized subset of $\{0,1\}^{|w|}$ such that all pairs in the subset are unrelated by that definition?

Comment: The answer could potentially depend on which universal mechanism is used to define $K$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus two incompressible strings of a given length cannot be related by this  K(w1,w2)=K(w1)+K(w2) as it would break that rule --since most strings are incompressible most are unrelated. Is this along the lines of an answer? How much could choice of K vary the answer--not more than a constant right?

Comment: The choice of $K$ varies the Kolmogorov complexity by at most a constant.

Comment: May be of interest: http://www.jptheorygroup.org/doc/Birthday.pdf
"Sufficiently sized random subsets of strings are guaranteed to have two members x and y with low K(x/y)"